# C# Not sure how to resolve issues

Tags: c#

This is all the code we have been given as part of this course.

We have been asked to sort the issues with the code:

The variable 'name' is assigned but is never used.
and
Cannot covert 'String' to 'Bool'

But that's where i get stuck. 
Code:

```
string name = "Fred";
decimal value = (name == "Fred") ? 15 : Math.Sqrt(100);
```

Comment: Is this your actual code?

Comment: `"` is not the same as `“`...

Comment: So i am on a course an we have to fix the issues... yes that's the code.

Comment: What is the expected outcome and what errors are you experiencing

Comment: Can you give a more specific description of the "issues"? What are the error messages?

Comment: Ok but how do i tell the difference between the 2 things you have listed?

Comment: So, it saying cannot convert a type 'string' to 'bool'

Comment: So i have sorted the Fred issue

Comment: Its saying that 'name' isn't being used as well?

Comment: None of this makes sense. Please make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/) of your problem

Comment: That code (as you've posted it here) should work. So you must be doing something strange to get errors.

Comment: Ok so i have updated the question with some context.

Comment: I repeat *That code (as you've posted it here) should work. So you must be doing something strange to get errors.*

Answer (score 1):

`Math.Sqrt` returns a double, you need to cast it to `decimal`

```
string name = "Fred";
decimal value = (name == "Fred") ? 15 : (decimal)Math.Sqrt(100);
```

Comment: Thanks, that sorted all the issues out!

Comment: This would in no way produce the errors you we're saying it produces. It's extremely frustrating when questions include incorrect information, badly formatted code, etc. Please take more care when asking questions and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) @Scottish_Calum

Comment: Hi @Liam, in scottish_Calum's defence, I posted his code into an empty method in VS2015 and got the errors that he stated. Upon splitting the declaration and assignment of value, I received the more informative 'Cannot convert type 'double' to 'decimal'. I think this could be a case of a learner being misled by the foibles of Visual Studio as his initial errors were certainly not intuitive.

Comment: There was also the issue of his [initial question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/49381593/1) using weird characters and a non consistent string case too though, point taken though. Interestingly the OP hasn't even bothered to upvote this answer (that was me) let alone accept it...